# How to create Visual Studio 2015 solution from CMake

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015, cmake

We have a CMakeList.txt prepared to work with IDE's like QT Creator, so some team members are using two different solutions, one for Release and a different one for Debug, respectively.

I would like to use Visual Studio 2015, so I need to create one single solution considering both configurations (Release & Debug). How can I set the different configuration flags properly?

Now, CMakeList file looks like this:

```
if(CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE STREQUAL "Debug")
    message("Debug Build")
    set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "/DWIN32 /D_WINDOWS /W3 /wd4996 /wd4251 /wd4275 /wd4267 /GR /EHsc /MP")

else()
    message("Release Build")
    set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "/DWIN32 /D_WINDOWS /WX /W3 /wd4996 /wd4251 /wd4275 /wd4267 /GR /EHsc /MP /Ox")
endif()
```

So I just can create one single solution adding `-D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE = Release` or `Debug`.
I would like to generate a single solution and then, from VS decide to compile as Debug or Release.

Comment: `CMake` supports multiconfigurations in Visual Studio so you don't have to configure for only Debug or Release. Just get rid of the `-D CUSTOM_BUILD_TYPE`  part and it should create a solution with the following 4 configurations: Debug, Release, RelMinSize and RelWithDebInfo

Answer (score 2):

Visual Studio is a multi-configuration generator, so you can easily switch between Release and Debug. No need to use a `CUSTOM_BUILD_TYPE` argument. In addition, CMake provides [generator expressions](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-generator-expressions.7.html#variable-queries) (e.g. `$<$<CONFIG:Debug>: ... >`) for setting configuration-specific options such as those in your example. The flags look very similar between Release and Debug, so you can use a generator expression to simply add the extra Release flags.

Also, manually manipulating the `CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS` variable is discouraged. It is much safer and cleaner to set these flags using [`target_compile_options()`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/target_compile_options.html):

```
target_compile_options(YourTarget PRIVATE
    /DWIN32 /D_WINDOWS W3 /wd4996 /wd4251 /wd4275 /wd4267 /GR /EHsc /MP
    $<$<CONFIG:Release>:/WX;/Ox>
)
```